# SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION when I install django-constance

Tags: python, django, pip

I can not install the django-constance.

Steps to reproduce

```
$ pip3 install django-constance
Collecting django-constance
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-constance/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-constance (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-constance
```

System configuration

```
Django version:
$ django-admin --version
1.11.1

Python version:
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

to upgrade the pip to the latest version, instead of `pip3 install -upgrade pip`.

then re-install the `django-constance`.